# How do I extract a snapped off PVC nipple?

Tags: sprinkler-system, pvc

I have a 3/4" PVC sprinkler system, and one of the nipples has snapped off inside the 1/2" threaded fitting. I have a [nipple extractor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I1RQZ8) which has worked very well in the past but I guess this time I didn't press hard enough at the beginning as all it does is shave the inside of the nipple. How do I get this thing out without pulling the whole pipe up and replacing the fitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was not ideal; it might have been less work just to dig out the section of pipe. With that in mind, I followed the suggestion of another site to use a [mini hacksaw similar to this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003N2J0VM) to cut several notches in the body of the nipple (stopping short of the threads). Then I gently pounded in the larger size nipple extractor with a small mallet and twisted. The nipple broke in half, and from there it was a simple matter to pull out the two pieces with a pair of pliers.